# fullscreen overlay that receives, but does not consume, touch events

Tags: android

I am interested in making a timer for speedrunning android games.

I want my app to be an overlay that detects when the screen is tapped (to start the timer), but also passes all taps through (so you can start the timer and the game with a single tap). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

Fortunately, no, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons. Spyware authors would love it if they could spy on user touch input in this fashion.

Comment: You can *record the user's screen* on Android along with the locations of their touch presses (which would even allow you to see hidden passwords), and you could potentially mail the recording to yourself. I don't see how having an overlay could be any more dangerous than that.

Comment: @Entity: "You can record the user's screen on Android along with the locations of their touch presses" -- and the user is explicitly told about this and has to agree to it at the time of the recording. The rights to record the screen only last as long as your process does. "I don't see how having an overlay could be any more dangerous than that" -- an overlay only needs permission at the time of installation/first run.

Comment: Exactly. The overlay could have the exact same sort of permissions. The overlay isn't just "there," it would of course be a process too.

Comment: @Entity: "The overlay could have the exact same sort of permissions" -- it doesn't, at least through Android 6.0. You are welcome to make a contribution to the AOSP that offers this, I suppose.

Comment: The overlay doesn't exist at all was my understanding. My point was, though, that it could be implemented in a secure way that respects the user's privacy. I would imagine it wouldn't have many uses, though, which is probably the reason nobody has bothered to add it.

Comment: @Entity: "The overlay doesn't exist at all was my understanding" -- you can have a full-screen overlay. Your choices are either to consume the touch events (and therefore the underlying app doesn't get them) or not receive the touch events (in which case you don't know when the user has tapped). "My point was, though, that it could be implemented in a secure way that respects the user's privacy" -- yes, my answer was focused on the current state of Android. Android could be modified to support your scenario.